# Overriding loadView and setting rootViewController programmatically, no Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, programmatically-created

I'm trying to create and set a `View` as the root `View` programmatically. I'm not using a Storyboard or ARC.

I'm trying to set a `UIWebView` as my `ViewController's` root `View`, which I'm unable to do. When I run the following code, I see a `NavigationBar` with a blank white screen. I tried setting a regular `UIView` as the root `View` and set its background color to blue, which loaded, so the problem seems to be specific to a `UIWebView`.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Here is my `loadView` code:

```
// in GmailOAuthViewController.m
- (void)loadView {

    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

    self.view = webView;
}
```

And here is my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[GmailOAuthViewController alloc] init];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning self.view...
if you assign webView to view everything else is gone
try

```
[self.view addSubview: webView]
```

this is code i just tried and it works

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

in ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] ;
    webView.delegate = self;
    self.view = webView;

    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ViewControllerCatalog" ofType:@"pdf"];
    if (thePath) {
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [(UIWebView *)self.view loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
                        textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }

}
```

I apologize I told you wrong earlier you do in fact assign to view

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. If I make your change, the screen never transitions away from the copyright screen. I've created no parent views other than this `UIWebView` and am not using a Storyboard. I'd like to set it as the root `View` and display it programmatically.

Comment: the above code works i just drug a pdf with that name into Xcode and all is good. I guess your navigation controller property was interfering with the existing property

Comment: Thanks, I messed around myself and found that the UIWebView class doesn't come with an address bar, which is why I couldn't recognize it as a UIWebview.